# $T$ is invertible implies $T^* $is invertible

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $T\in L(\mathbb{H})$ such that $\mathbb{H}$ is a Hilbert space . show that the following Conditions are  equivalent : 
$i)$ T is invertible 
$ii)$ T* is invertible 
$iii)$ there is $w>0$ such that $\|T(x)\| \geq \omega\|x\|$ and $\left\|T^{*}(x)\right\| \geq \omega\|x\|$ $\forall x \in \mathbb{H}$. 
My attempt :
$i)$ and $ii)$ $\implies$ $iii)$ i used the Open mapping theorem. 
$iii)$$ \implies$ $i)$ and $ii)$ i used the fact that injectivity and closed range implies invertibility.
But i don't know how to prove $i) \implies ii)$

Comment: Best thing is just to find an inverse. It is not hard to guess what the inverse of $T^*$ should be.

Comment: @Mark the inverse of $T^*$ is $(T^*)^{-1})$ . I start by $T T^{-1}= I$ since $I^*= I$ so $T^*( T^{-1} )^* = I$

Comment: Yes. More precisely, $T^*(T^{-1})^*=(T^{-1}T)^*$, because conjugation reverses the order of multiplication. But the conclusion is still the same, $T^*(T^{-1})^*=I$. (and similarly, $(T^{-1})^*T^*=I$).

Comment: @Mark But still have to show that $( T^{-1} )^* =(T^{*} )^{-1}$ ?

Comment: @vemapo: Once you have shown that $T^*B=I$ and $BT^*=I$ for some $B$, then by definition $B=(T^*)^{-1}$.

Comment: OK THANK YOU ALL!!!